# UrlClassLoader not working as expected in appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlclassloader

I am uploading a JAR to the appengine blobstore and then trying to load a class using that jar.

```
jarURL = new URL("http://giffycrm.appspot.com/serve?blob-key="+blobKey);
        System.err.println("jarURL : "+jarURL);
        ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                new URL[] { jarURL },
                //getClass().getClassLoader()
                JarUtils.class.getClassLoader()
                );
        System.err.println("ClassLoader : "+loader);
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            //clazz = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
            clazz = loader.loadClass(className);
            System.err.println("clazz : "+clazz);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object o = clazz.newInstance();
        System.err.println("Object create : "+o);
        Method m = clazz.getMethod(methodName, String.class);
        System.err.println("Method Called : "+m.getName());
        String returnVal = (String) m.invoke(o, "jude");
        System.err.println("return value : "+returnVal);
```

The class is not loading at this line: clazz = loader.loadClass(className);

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Is your jar available if you try the url in the browser?

Comment: Yes it is. I can download the jar with the URL directly from the browser.

Comment: This may well not be permitted on google appengine, it seems to push the boundaries of the concept of the PaaS sandbox. URLClassLoader is available on the whitelist, if you can show the exception/error stacktrace that will help people diagnose the issue.